# What to do with the [learning] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-blacklist

I have noticed that many questions tagged as [learning](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) are closed. I counted in the first 100 questions only 34 were not closed. I think it gives the false impression that questions like "Where can I learn...?" or "How do I start with...?" are welcomed.

- Do you think it should be removed?
- Maybe suggesting another tag that is more clear about the usage. (I could not think of one)

Comment: As of now, there are 545 questions that are open (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=[learning]+closed%3A0) vs 245 that are closed (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=[learning]+closed%3A1). Doesn't look too bad by Prog.SE standards

Comment: @gant You convinced me, and thanks for showing me the `closed:0\1` option.